# How to Pass extra parameters to a custom UIView class for initialization in swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I'm trying to write a class that is of type UIView, but on initialization I want it to take an extra parameter, but I can't figure out how to get around the UIView needing its params instead. Any help is much appreciated!

```
class MenuBar: UIView {

    let homeController: HomeController

    init(controller: HomeController){
        homeController = controller
        super.init()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

In the ViewController I'm initializing it like this:

```
let menuBar: MenuBar = {
    let mb = MenuBar(controller: self)
    return mb
}()
```

Comment: I don't think that view holding view controller is a good idea. You can introduce retain cycle ...

Comment: Just use the good ol' `NSUserDefaults` inside your `init(frame: CGRect)`. If you don't care too much about elegance, this will do the job without introducing any retain cycle.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this.

```
class MenuBar: UIView {

    let homeController: HomeController

    required init(controller: HomeController){
        homeController = controller
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        // Can't call super.init() here because it's a convenience initializer not a desginated initializer
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is key, handling the required init that you don't want by throwing fatalError.

Answer (score 10):

From my experience this is what works best if you want to have custom initialiser for `UIView`:

```
class CustomView : UIView {
    private var customProperty: CustomClass

    required init(customProperty: CustomClass) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.customProperty = customProperty
        self.setup()
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    fileprivate func setup() {
        //Here all custom code for initialisation (common for all creation methods)
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to keep common initialisation code regardless of method of creating the view (both storyboard and code)

That's about creating UIView properly.

Additionally I would recommend to avoid passing `UIViewController` to `UIView` - I think you are trying to solve some problem in a wrong way.

Much better ways to communicate between those two is to use `delegate` or `closure` - but that's a bit off-topic - maybe you can create another question about why you want to pass it like this.

Comment: He needs to pass parameters into view during initialization. I think the best way of doing this here is to assign properties after initialization and then trigger setup() method.

Comment: Hey @grzegorzKrukowski, thanks for this idea. What I'm trying to do is dependency injection of a viewController into this class. I tried to implement your code and part of it passes, however the last 2 required inits throw errors that say this in the IDE: Property 'self.customProperty' not initialized at super.init call...

Comment: @AndyC - Yes the method of assigning it after initialization works, but being that im trying to do dependency injection, ideally would be great if it was always a dependent. If I do it after initialization, it forces me to make the property an optional, but it works hahaha.

Comment: While this didn't work right off the bat - the structure of the code is very clean and organized and I will combine the 2 answers with some modification which I think would be the best option. So just wanted to say thank you!